# There are things I cannot do with my other laptop like changing some settings and opening certain folders

Tags: windows-8, administrator

There are things I cannot do with my other laptop like changing some settings and opening certain folders.

It sometimes says:

> Access denied, only administrators can access this and such, some settings are managed by the system administrator, please contact your system administrator.

I'm wondering who the administrator was.

I'm the only one who has ever used that laptop. I'm the one who installed the OS as per the instructions included on the packaging, I'm also the only one who installed all the software and utilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are using windows 8 because of the tag. the administrator account is the Microsoft or local account that was used or created, respectively. if you are using that account you could try activating the hidden administrator account [Go here for instructions, general precautions and comments on the topic](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9650-built-administrator-account-enable-disable-windows-8-a.html). to solve the files problem make sure that you have access to them. If youy want to use brute force go here [go here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/). I know it say Windows 7 and vista but it also works on Windows 8 I have used it before.